# Read input from jquery timepicker and pass it to php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, shell

I'm noob in front end scripting and need some help on making javascript.

Using google, I was able to made some progress, but can't get to then required results.

I have shell script, which is working as expected. Now I need to create simple UI for users, where they will enter start_date and end_date for report, this need to be grabbed and passed to shell script.

I have read, that it is not possible to call directly shell script from javascript, so I'm calling simple PHP file, which in turn execute shell script.

As of now my javascript can do this actions and shell script is executing.

I need to add functionality to grab start_date and end_date and what is important convert it to unix tick format and pass it to shell script.

Here is my scripts

javascript

```js
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datetimepicker1,#datetimepicker2" ).datetimepicker();
  });
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function submitAction()  {

$.ajax({
  url:"report.php",
  type: "POST"
})
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Start Date: <input type="text" id="datetimepicker1"></p>
<p>End Date: <input type="text" id="datetimepicker2"></p>
<p><input type="button" onclick="submitAction()" value="Get Report" /></p>

 
</body>
</html>
```

php

```html
<?php
$output = exec("./exceptions_report.sh 1427955771711 1427998971711");
echo 'Report will be sent to your mail';
?>
```

shell

```html
startdate=$1
enddate=$2
curl -X POST  {http://localhost:9200/_search?} -d '{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"bool":{"should":[{"query_string":{"query":"*"}}]}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"@timestamp":{"from":$startdate,"to":$enddate}}},{"terms":{"level.raw":["ERROR"]}}]}}}},"size":1900,"fields":["logdate","level","device_id","thread","category","messagetext"],"sort":[{"@timestamp":{"order":"asc","ignore_unmapped":true}},{"@timestamp":{"order":"asc","ignore_unmapped":true}}]
      }' > input.json
#
cat input.json | jq '.hits.hits[].fields' --compact-output | sed 's/[][]//g' | recs tocsv --key logdate,level,device_id,thread,category,messagetext > report.csv
#
mail -s "Exceptions report" -a report.csv "mail_adress" << EOM
Please find exceptions report attached.
EOM
#
```

Comment: You need to use form html element and then in ajax call pass data as form serialize. in php side, grab those date and pass to exec function.

Comment: I would appreciate, if somebody can provide some example of this process.   And what is important as well, need to convert date to unix tick fromat, before passing it to shell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html, add a form, like this:

```
<form id="form" action="" method="POST">
  <p>Start Date: <input type="text" name="date_1" id="datetimepicker1"></p>
  <p>End Date: <input type="text" name="date_2" id="datetimepicker2"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Get Report" /></p>
</form>
<div id="AjaxResult"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
      url:"report.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      success: function(data){
        $('#AjaxResult').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

- Here we use [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for the form data
- and fire the ajax on submit of the `#form`
- The result from report.php will be returned to the `#AjaxResult` div in your html
- [`e.prventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) cancels the default form submit action which will
  prevent the page from refreshing,

---

In your PHP (report.php), you can get those input values like this:

```
<?php

$date_1 = $_POST['date_1'];
$date_2 = $_POST['date_2'];

echo $date_1 . "<br>";
echo $date_2 . "<br>";

$output = exec("./exceptions_report.sh 1427955771711 1427998971711");
echo 'Report will be sent to your mail';

?>
```

Which will output:

```
04/08/2015 00:00 // user selection
04/10/2015 00:00 // user selection
Report will be sent to your mail
```

inside of `<div id="AjaxResult"></div>` using the [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method in the success callback

Comment: Thanks you very much M.Doye, this was really awesome and helpful

Answer (score 0):

Small correction, which may be usefull to others. During testing of this, I have found that to ensure correct passing of variables to shell script, need to use escapeshellarg in php.

$date_1 = escapeshellarg($_POST['date_1']);
$date_2 = escapeshellarg($_POST['date_2']);